# Add JS to CRUD view to interact with fields

Tags: laravel-backpack

I followed this github pull comments https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/pull/4312

I added to the crud controller

```
        Widget::add()->type('script')->content('/js/hotel.js');
```

and also this fields

```
        CRUD::field('caption');
        CRUD::field('slug');
```

Created hotel.js with one of the functions in the example mentioned  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tabacitu/248dd59da9b33debc26cb7496f205bb5/raw/2477e2aef02facbc9ffc08cdceff20c82eab493a/product-form.js

```
function slugify(string) {
    const a = 'àáâäæãåāăąçćčđďèéêëēėęěğǵḧîïíīįìıİłḿñńǹňôöòóœøōõőṕŕřßśšşșťțûüùúūǘůűųẃẍÿýžźż·/_,:;'
    const b = 'aaaaaaaaaacccddeeeeeeeegghiiiiiiiilmnnnnoooooooooprrsssssttuuuuuuuuuwxyyzzz------'
    const p = new RegExp(a.split('').join('|'), 'g')

    return string.toString().toLowerCase()
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // Replace spaces with -
        .replace(p, c => b.charAt(a.indexOf(c))) // Replace special characters
        .replace(/&/g, '-and-') // Replace & with 'and'
        .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '') // Remove all non-word characters
        .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-') // Replace multiple - with single -
        .replace(/^-+/, '') // Trim - from start of text
        .replace(/-+$/, '') // Trim - from end of text
}
crud.field('caption').change(function(e, value) {
    var slug = slugify(value);
    crud.field('slug').input.val(slug);
});
```

The JS is loaded correctly when I reload the CRUD view, but when I modify the caption field nothing happens I don't get any JS error, but the slug field doesn't change either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the script to

```
crud.field('caption').onChange(field => {
    crud.field('slug').input.value = slugify(field.value);
})
```

and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you are using PRO, if you are, there is already a slug field type, no need to manually create it. `CRUD::field('slug')->type('slug')`.

Cheers

Comment: Hi! slug was just an example. The problem was with JS, thanks!